# Rails ActionMailer Plugin for TLS encryption

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, ssl

Can anyone point me to a plugin/directions for enabling emails through a smtp server requiring encryption?  I've done some searching and found http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/actionmailer_tls , but the download is down, a pattern repeated with several other plugins also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using at least Ruby 1.8.7, you don't need any plugins, you just need to configure ActionMailer to use TLS by putting `:enable_starttls_auto => true` into `config.action_mailer.smtp_settings`.